# SVD properties - what can we say about connections between different ranks of distortion?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, svd

A reminder and notations for the singular value decomposition (SVD) and the Eckart-Young theorem:

Let the SVD of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ be $UDV^T$, where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ are orthogonal matrices, and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ such that the values on the main diagonal of $D$ are non-negative and ordered in decreasing order ($\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2\ge \cdots \ge \sigma_m \ge 0$) and the other entrances of $D$ are zeros.

Let $1 \le r \le m$ and denote $A_r = UD_rV^T$, where $D_r$ is $D$ with the values $\sigma_{r+1}...\sigma_{m}$ replaced by zeros.

The Eckart-Young theorem states that:

$$ A_r = \underset{B\ :\ rank(B)=r}{\mbox{argmin}} \| A - B \|_F $$

where $\| \cdot \|_F$ is the Frobenius norm. The above immediately implies that given $A_{r_1}$ and $A_{r_2}$ such that $r_1 < r_2$, it holds that

$$ \| A - A_{r_1} \|_F > \| A - A_{r_2} \|_F$$

Similarly, due to the uniqueness of the SVD, denoting $U'D'V'^T$ as the SVD of $A_{r_2}$, then $A_{r_1}$ can be derived from $A_{r_2}$ by zeroing the $r_2 - r_1$ smallest values on the main diagonal of $D'$, namely:
$$A_{r_1} = U'D'_{r_1}V'^T$$
($D'_{r_1}$ is defined in the same way as $D_r$ above just with $r_1$.)

Are there any other connections between $A_{r_1}$ and $A_{r_2}$?

Comment: You’ve defined the matrix $A_r$; what are you claiming about it? Also, what does a “ratio” between two matrices mean?

Comment: Well, I forgot to define how $A_r$ is received from the SVD, my bad. I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: @AmihayElboher This question seems a bit vague. Is there something in particular that you're trying to do? What kind of "connection" between these matrices are you looking for?

Comment: You are right, the point is that the only theorem I know about SVD and matrix approximation is Eckart-Young, and of course, things about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the diagonal matrices that I denoted as $A_r$.  To be clearer, Eckart-Young talks about "connection"(/"ratio") in terms of Frobenius norm. Another "connection" is that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A_{r_1}$ are subset of those of $A_{r_2}$. Is there anything else of that kind? Maybe something regarding other norms? (I do understand that the words "of that kind" are vague, but I hope it's clearer now.) Thanks!